# How to abort a request?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an upload script. If there's an error while writing to disk I want to abort the request and return a 500 status code.

My code (below) sends a `500` as expected, but the upload doesn't stop. I keep getting "data" events until the upload is complete (even though my write pipe is already broken) and then the `req.on('end'` event fires which tries to send a `204` even though I've already sent a `500`.

How can I abort the request so that I stop getting event notifications?

```
var filename = req.headers['wx-filename'];
var docType = req.headers['wx-doc-type'];
var clientId = req.headers['wx-client-id'];

var dir = Path.join(config.storage_path, docType, clientId);
var filePath = Path.join(dir, filename);

mkdirp.sync(dir);

var destFile = FileSystem.createWriteStream(filePath, {
    flags: 'wx' // don't overwrite files
});

if (config.env === 'dev') {
    (function () {
        var fileSize = req.headers['content-length'];
        var uploadedBytes = 0;

        req.on('data', function (data) {
            uploadedBytes += data.length;
            var p = uploadedBytes / fileSize * 100;
            var fn = Path.relative(config.storage_path, filePath);
            util.log(fn + ': ' + p.toFixed(1) + '%');
        });
    })();
}

req.on('end', function () {
    util.log("END");
    resp.writeHead(204);
    resp.end();
});

destFile.on('error', function (err) {
    util.log("ERROR", err);
    resp.writeHead(500, err.code);
    resp.end();
    // HOW TO STOP REQUEST?
});

req.pipe(destFile);
```

Comment: Did you try `req.end`?

Comment: @thefourtheye `req.end()` and `req.abort()` are undefined.

Comment: Okay, how about `req.socket.end()`?

Comment: @thefourtheye That exists. I called it. It doesn't stop the 'data' events from coming in though.

Comment: Did you try `req.emit('error')`? Keep in mind that `data` event won't stop immediately, for it could happen that some chunks are still pending. You can safely remove the listeners from the `data` event in any case and discard the reference to the request object.

Comment: @skypjack Can't emit an "error" event on `req`. Says that event is unspecified. I didn't think about unbinding the listener. I suppose I could do that. I was hoping to save the client a little bit of bandwidth, uploading a file that will never succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [remove the listeners](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_removelistener) for `data` and `end`, after that send a `Connection: close` header and at the end send the 500 error.

Comment: Aha! Sending `Connection: close` seems to actually kill it. Thank you! I was more worried about the client sending more data than it needs to than receiving a few extra events.